# Passing a big amount of data to a Parse Query

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Im working with an application that uses a table with (name, gender) as a schema. This is used to retrieve the gender of a given name. So what im struggling to achieve here is to give parse an Array with thousands of names and return as result the gender for each name. Can I make it with one Parse call only?

I tried using Parse.Query.or with a query for each name but sadly this only supports 10 different queries.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse can return only 1000 records per query at most. So if you have N number of names. It will require minimum N/1000 queries.

Reference for parse limitations http://profi.co/all-the-limits-of-parse/

To optimally make queries you can make a batch of 1000 names and make query to Parse and set limit to 1000. Then iterate all the records and generate a dictionary. But to make it even more faster you can make those calls asynchronously.

Example

```
// function to fetch gender of list of names
function fetchGenderOfNames(arrayOfNames, successCallback, errorCallback){
    var numberOfBatches = (arrayOfNames.length/1000 + (arrayOfNames.length % 1000)? 1 : 0),
        callCount = 0,
        genderOfNames = {},
        errorFlag = false;
    function querySuccessCallback(records){
        if(!errorFlag){
            records.forEach(function(record){
                genderOfNames[record.get('name')] = record.get('gender');
            });
            callCount++;
            if(callCount == numberOfBatches){
                successCallback(genderOfNames);
            }
        }
    }
    function queryErrorCallback(error){
        if(!errorFlag){
            errorFlag = true;
            errorCallback(error);
        }
    }
    for(var arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < arrayOfNames.length; arrayIndex += 1000){
        if(!errorFlag){
            var genderQuery = new Parse.Query('Table_name');
            // following match will be case sensitive
            genderQuery.containedIn('name', arrayOfNames.slice(arrayIndex, arrayIndex + 1000);
            genderQuery.limit(1000);
            genderQuery.find({success: querySuccessCallback, error: queryErrorCallback});
        }
    }
}
```